# How to Configure Jenkins Login in iPad using Unity

Tags: ios, ipad, unity-game-engine, jenkins, unityscript

I had installed Jenkins in network and making build successfully.

I want to have authentication for my iPad app, developed with unity.  I searched the plugin respective to this, but i can't find it. whether this can be attained by means of plugin or otherways?

As i need to login into my jenkins and afterward use the data of pipelines and all in my app accessed through URL so need login first.

Please do let me know the ways to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Jenkins is not supposed to accomplish such tasks. Wrong tech used.

Comment: @David thanks for your reply..
Okay, here is more clarification.
Like we do login in any app through facebook api and get it's details like friends and other.
I want to do same for jenkins.
Do login in jenkins through app and access it's data.

Comment: I think you are doing automatic UI testing, in this way, you can keep your login credentials into a text file, which can be accessed by Jenkins, but again, this is nothing related to Unity.

Comment: Yes i can do it that way but if i am not login in jenkins proper then it won't let me access the data.
Because i am making an app in unity in which i need to show jenkins project details like jobs, pipelines and rest.
Which i am getting by accessing web url.
But the issue is if i try to access that url from my app without login then it gives me an error.
So without login i cannot access jenkins data.

And that's the reason i need to login though my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and all i found the solution for this and i used following code to check authentication.

```
public void TryLogin ()
{
    UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get ("Your jenkins login url of network");
    req.method = "GET";
    req.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("jenkinsId:jenkinsPassword")));

    StartCoroutine (WaitForLoginRequest (req));
}

IEnumerator WaitForLoginRequest(UnityWebRequest req)
{
    yield return req.Send ();

    if (req.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log ("WWW Error: " + req.error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Ok!:");

        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (req.downloadHandler.data);
        Debug.Log ("Response code = " + req.responseCode);
        Debug.Log ("String = " + response);
    }    
}
```

And check the response code for authentication.